# Grab last youtube video index and re-download .description

Tags: bash, filenames, text, youtube-dl

after I had download youtube videos with youtube-dl -cit -f 140 ' , I forget to download the .description as well... so I have bunch of files without description, I want to redownload the description of those file e.g.
American Patriotic Songs and Marches-BJepYzH1VUY.m4a . Best of Chopin-AM1cL_EB_nQ.m4a...

ie. a bash script to grab the last 11 characters of the filename and then download the description.. I tried to use for loop , but it broke when handling filename with space, special characters, .... (lastpart=`echo -n ${filebase%.*} | tail -c11`
)

Let me summarize:
1) for i in $(ls | grep m4a)
2) grab the last 11 chars from filename
e.g. Rachmaninoff - Piano Concerto No. 2 & Schumann - Piano Concerto-1oRfva8UKeY.m4a
-> grab 1oRfva8UKeY and pass to youtube-dl
3) start youtube-dl --skip-download --youtube-skip-dash-manifest --write-description -f 140 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1oRfva8UKeY '

thanks

Comment: What have you got so far? If you show us the command(s)/script formatted as such it's easier to debug.

Comment: I got it, though a dumb solution, it will echo all the commands and i simply add bash at the top and run ..#!/bin/bash

for filename in *.m4a
do
    echo -n "youtube-dl --skip-download --youtube-skip-dash-manifest --write-description "
    echo -n  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="
    echo  ${filename%.*} | tail -c12
done

Answer (score 1):

[Use More Quotes™](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes). And [Don't Parse `ls`™](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).